# add cms block to product page

Tags: xml, magento, layout

Good day,

I would like to replace the [name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data"] block with a CMS block on a single product page.  The last example below [1] looks promising.  Below [2] is my attempted layout update XML.  This layout update indeed removes the product_type_data block, but the available_soon block is missing from the product page.

Is it possible to use an XML layout update to add a CMS block to a single product page?  Any clues would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

-Ben

[1]
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

[2]

```
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="unsetChild">
<name>product_type_data</name>
</action>
<block type="cms/block" name="available_soon" before="-">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>available-soon</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Double check the Static Block Identifier is 'available_soon'.

Add the following to your product page > Custom Layout:

```
<reference name="product.info">
 <action method="unsetChild">
  <name>product_type_data</name>
 </action>
 <block type="page/html" name="available_temp" as="available_temp" template="page/html/available_temp.phtml">
  <action method="setBlockId">
   <block_id>available_temp</block_id>
  </action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

Create the following file at app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/page/html/available_temp.phtml
and enter this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('available_soon')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed the identifier from available-soon to available_soon and tried your suggested layout update.  Unfortunately, the available_soon block is still missing from the product page.  It did not help to clear the cache.

Comment: I needed to change both the layout and the template, but the XML Layout Update only changes the layout.

From page 48 of the Magento Designer's Guide:  "You have seen that the layout files in Magento control the presence or absence of each content block in a theme.  What, specifically, gets rendered inside of that block is controlled by the template files."

An analogy for the Magento layout and template could be the HTML DOM and CSS.  Even though I add a block to the DOM, it may still be hidden.  Even though I add CSS to make a block visible, it may target a block that is absent from the DOM.

Comment: Try changing your code per the edit I made above. Using the Layout Update XML > template > static block you can accomplish this.